# Can the Arcanist take the same exploit more than once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

Ive made mistakes on this type of thing before which is why I am asking.

I cant see anywhere in the rules, but can the [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist) take the [exploit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits) [Metamagic Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/metamagic-knowledge) more than once? For example if I used it to take Empower Spell and then Maximize Spell 2 levels later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the Arcanist description of the feature at http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist#TOC-Arcanist-Exploits it explicitly tells you that you cannot:

> An arcanist exploit cannot be selected more than once.